# How to merge two or more models in RDF4J (formerly Sesame)?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, sesame, rdf4j

In Apache Jena there is a way to append one model to another by just calling `model1.add(model2)`, for example.

Is this also possible with RDF4J in case you interpret a model just as a set of statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse RDF4J, a [Model](http://docs.rdf4j.org/javadoc/latest/?org/eclipse/rdf4j/model/Model.html) is a Java Collection (similar to a `Set` or a `List`). So you can use standard Java collection operations. To append two models, simply do:

```
model1.addAll(model2);
```

Note that this operation only appends statements. If `model2` contains any namespace declarations that you wish to copy over as well, you will have to do that separately. For example, to have `model2` namespace declarations simply copied over, overwriting any existing declarations in `model1`:

```
model2.getNamespaces().stream().forEach(model1::setNamespace);
```

Or if you only wish to copy over those prefixes for which `model1` has no declaration yet:

```
model2.getNamespaces().stream()
      .filter(ns -> !model1.getNamespace(ns.getPrefix()).isPresent())
      .forEach(model1::setNamespace);
```